# Rails: Dynamically Building Forms and Saving Responses

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a sort of survey-style project where I need to dynamically create a form based off a `Question`'s `Choice`'s. I've gotten decently far but have run into some issues. `Question` is a simple model that `has_many :choices`. `Choice` has a polymorphic content type that can be represented by anything, in this case things like inputs, check boxes, radio buttons, etc. I want to have a survey page list the questions and choices associated with that question.

So I have this:

**/views/survey/index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Survey</h1>

<%= form_for @response do |f| %>
  <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
      <%= render question, f: builder %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit 'Get Response' %>
<% end %>
```

**app/views/questions/_question.html.erb**

```
<h3><%= question.title %></h3>
<% question.choices.each do |choice| %>
  <%= f.fields_for "question-#{question.id}" do |builder| %>
    <%= render choice, f: builder %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And an example of a choice partial:
**app/views/choice_inputs/_choice_input.html.erb**

```
<%= f.label choice_input.label %>
<%= f.text_field choice_input.label %>
```

Is this the best way of going about this? The problem, at least I think, with this is the html being generated gives me form names like:
`response[questions][question-2][tell us more]`

I also don't understand how to build a `Response` object to this. Should I loop through the `params` in my `ResponseController` and assign `Answer`'s to each `Question`? Also how would I go about permitting each question in the `params`?

I could see `params.require(:response).permit(:question-1, :qustion-2, :etc...)` getting way out of hand. Thanks for any input on this!